# onclick event doesn't fire in firefox or chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, onclick

I am coding some javascript with jQuery to fire when an img is clicked in my asp.net page.

The img is declared as follows:

```
<img id="zoomIn" alt="Zoom In" src="/Images/Plus.png" onclick="zoomIn();" />
```

And the .js file function is:

```
function zoomIn() {
    zoomLevel += 1;
    showMapImage();
}

function showMapImage() {
    //show the location map
    var img_url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + $asp("lblCoordinates").html() + "&size=200x150&sensor=false&zoom=" + zoomLevel + "&markers=color:green%7C" + $asp("lblCoordinates").html();
    $("#imgMap").attr('src', img_url);
}

function $asp(serverID) {
    return $("[id$='" + serverID + "']");
}
```

This works fine in IE but not in Chrome or Firefox which makes me think there is something simple wrong somewhere that I can't spot

Comment: would you like in zoomIn() function put just alert("it works"); and comment other lines to be sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You page contain two elements with same name\id: `IMG` HTML element with ID attribute *`"zoomIn"`* and javascript *`function`* with name *`zoomIn`*.

Try to rename `function zoomIn` or `IMG#zoomIn`.

Comment: this definitely the cause then.

Answer (score 3):

since that you've already used jQuery, you can just use

```
$('#zoomIn').click(zoomIn);
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it inside of an anchor tag and style accordingly.

```
<a href="#" onclick="zoomIn();">
    <img id="zoomIn" alt="Zoom In" src="/Images/Plus.png" />
</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H57Vg/5/

Comment: `TypeError: zoomIn is not a function` in my FireFox16 Firebug for your jsfiddle.